# Create stop loss based on percentage of equity loss (drawdown)

Tags: pine-script

I would like to exit a trade based on this number (see image below); the drawdown / equity drop **during** a given trade (not after a trade is closed obviously, as this is the criteria to close the trade, hehe).

[image]

There is [strategy.risk.max_drawdown()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Drisk%7Bdot%7Dmax_drawdown), but this will stop the whole strategy, whereas I am just looking to close a single trade and then carry on with the strategy.

I did find [strategy.percent_of_equity](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dpercent_of_equity) which may be useful(?)—not sure as the only reference I could find had to do with settings for the entire `strategy()`, eg see https://kodify.net/tradingview/strategy-settings/order-size-equity-percentage/.

One sticky point I foresee is that I'm guessing it may be necessary to be able to compare the equity **before** the trade was opened with the **current** equity, and I don't know how that can be done.

In other words maybe something like this (made up variables):

```
my_max_drawdown_per_trade = input(5)

// ...(?)

close_order_drawdown_pct_reached = (price_before_trade_opened - current_price) * order_quantity == my_max_drawdown_per_trade * order_quantity

strategy.close("MyID",when=close_order_drawdown_pct_reached)
```

(That might be a bit off but something like that)

Or maybe there is a better way to do this.

Or maybe there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need just simple stop loss exit:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
strategy("sl in %%")

// random entry 
if bar_index % 2 == 0 and strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
if bar_index % 2 != 0 and strategy.position_size == 0
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)    

// exit with stop loss
percent2points(percent) =>
    strategy.position_size !=0 ? strategy.position_avg_price * percent / 100 / syminfo.mintick : na
slPcnt = input(10, title = "Stop Loss %%")
slPts = floor(percent2points(slPcnt))
strategy.exit("x", loss = slPts)
```

Comment: I've understood you need exit trade when trade drawdown reach some %%. This is equal to exit trade by stop loss. My example show how to do this.

Comment: `Is this stop loss based on the price change of the asset` - yes

Comment: Interestingly this does not produce any trades for me in the strategy tester.

Comment: what is the symbol and timeframe?